# render 'new' page as partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, restful-architecture, partials

i'm building this app where the user should be able to perform all rest actions in the same page. So below a table like the following:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3">Name</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">Lastname</div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">Schedule</div>
  <div class="col-lg-1"> </div>
  <div class="col-lg-1"> </div>
</div>
<div id="table-body-clients">
  <% @clients.each do |client| %>
    <%= render :partial => 'client', :locals => { :client => client } %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I should include a form to add a new client (same form will then load and edit selected clients. All on remote).

The easiest way i can think is to render 'new' page as a partial. But i don't seem to find the way to call the correct action and/or load the locals correctly.
This did not work:

```
<%= render 'new', :controller => "clients", :action => "new", :locals => { :client => @client } %>
```

- 'new' is actually a partial named '_new'

Anyway, I would appreciate a fix on this code as much as an insight for the right way to approach the issue.
Thanks

Comment: does `render partial: 'new', locals: { client: Client.new }` work?

Comment: no @MrYoshiji. "undefined local variable or method `client' for #<#<Class:0x00000004eb7388>:0x00000004eb5b28>". Maybe because im using device and Client extends User?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> should be able to perform all rest actions in the same page

Don't worry about performing actions on the same page - make sure you keep your views structured in the resourceful style of Rails, but call them in the view you want (much the same as you would with partials)

As you have demonstrated, you can do this:

```
<%= render "clients/new", locals: { client: @client } %>
```

To give you a caveat here, you need to appreciate that since you're creating a *new* `client`, you'll want to build the resource in your controller:

```
#app/controllers/clients_controller.rb
class ClientsController < ApplicationController
   def index
     @clients = Client.all
     @client = Client.new
   end
end
```

--

As you mention you've got a `nested route` (IE `client` belongs to `company`), you want to make sure you have the following set up:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :companies do
   resources :clients #-> domain.com/companies/:company_id/clients
end

#app/controllers/clients_controller.rb
class ClientsController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @clients = Client.all

      @company = Company.find params[:company_id]
      @client = Client.new
   end
end

#app/views/clients/index.html.erb
<%= render "new", locals: {company: @company, client: @client} %>

#app/views/clients/new.html.erb
<%= form_for [company, client] do |f| %>
   ...
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a partial `_form.html.erb` as the following

```
<%= form_for client do |f| %>
your form fields here
<% end %>
```

Then, from `new.html.erb` and `edit.html.erb`, or whatever page where you need the form:

```
<%= render "form", client: @client %>
```

Replace @client with the actual `client` object you need the form for.

Comment: no, same problem: "undefined local variable or method `client' for #<#<Class:0x00000004eb7388>:0x00000004eb5b28>" on _form.html

Comment: What version of ruby/rails are you using? Could you paste your actual `render` line (where you try to render the partial)?

Comment: thanks, it's fixed. I didn't realize client belongs to company, so it needed both arguments: <%= render :partial => 'form', :locals => { :company => company, :client => company.clients.build } %>